# Additional console window

Tags: c, windows, dll, console

I have application that has to write to console. Also I call function from dll that writes to stdout too. Now I want to have separate output window to get all output from dll there. (So I will have 2 console windows: one for client app, one for dll) How to make it? I use windows+mingw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  `stdout` is a single file handle and if both your application code and the dll are writing to it, they're going to go to the same place no matter what you do.

Your best options would be to either:

1. change your application code to write to something besides stdout (i.e stderr or a file), or
2. change your application code so that its output statements are 'tagged' in a way that you can filter using a tool like grep or sed/awk

Comment: Adpalumbo is right.  A process can have only one console. The only way to accomplish this would be to make it a GUI app and create two windows that look like a console window.